# Modify value of Firstname Customer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute

I have a custom attribute for customers but when I try to set any value to this attribute it does not save.

I have this code:

```
public function getAllow(){
  $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();    
  $customer->setAllowboms("0");
  $customer->save();
  return $customer->getAllowboms();
}
```

When I call the function `getAllow()` return the value 0 but if I comment `$customer->setAllowBoms('0');` and `$customer->save();` don't return any value.

Comment: what is the type of the attribute or any default value set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the customer attribute you have to initiate **customer model object** and then set the attribute and save the model as shown below

```
$customerId=1;
$customer =Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$customer->setAllowboms("0");
$customer->save();
```

After that you can retrieve that attribute value from customer session as shown below:

```
public function getAllow(){
 $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();    
 return $customer->getAllowboms();
}
```